# ImportError: undefined symbol: GDALDatasetTestCapability when installing gdal2tiles on Linux Centos 7.5

Tags: linux, python, centos-7

How can I resolve this error?

> ImportError: /home/a/b.com/live-charts/live-chart-example/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: GDALDatasetTestCapability

Answer (score -1):

Gerrit's answer to a related question solved the *undefined symbol: GDALDatasetTestCapability* error for me:

> If a gdal version is already installed, this problem will occur even if you have linked against the version installed in ~/.local.  A solution is given at a [Planet MYSQL](http://fr.planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=683010) post here:
>
> > In this case, we can tell the linker to preload our newer 1.11.0 library in our shell this way:
> >
> > `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1`
>
> Or, in my case,
>
> > `export LD_PRELOAD="$HOME/.local/lib/libgdal.so.1"`

[Python gdal undefined symbol GDALRasterBandGetVirtualMem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116402/python-gdal-undefined-symbol-gdalrasterbandgetvirtualmem)

Comment: You may also need to run,

    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` and 
    `ldconfig`

in order for the bindings to work.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a comment on the down vote.  This answer and information helped me resolve this exact error.